# Firestore getDoc wont work when using pathSegments in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a very simple data load from firebase but it wont work when I use path segments in react

something very simple as

```
import { getFirestore, getDoc, getDocs, setDoc, doc, updateDoc, getCollection, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { firebaseConfig } from "config";

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);


getDoc(doc(firestore, 'collection', ['path','to','document']));
```

it will throw an exception

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.split is not a function
```

how can i do to pass an array for that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#doc) doesn't take an array as param but path segments (strings). Try using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on array as shown below:

```
getDoc(doc(firestore, 'collection', ...['path','to','document']));
// spread syntax here                ⬆


// Equivalent to:
getDoc(doc(firestore, 'collection', 'path', 'to', 'document'));
```

`doc()` function signature from the documentation:

```
export declare function doc(firestore: Firestore, path: string, ...pathSegments: string[]): DocumentReference<DocumentData>;
```